# UITextField troubles centering placeholder and changing the keyboard color writing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

i'm actually working into a registration form into my iOs application.

I'm still quite new with iOs but I managed to make a good looking registration form thanks to uiTableViewCell customisation and uiTextField.

I'm facing 2 problems right now that I fail at solving actually:

1) When I align my UITextField on center, it does not really center it or maybe it does but then it starts writing my string at center instead of centering the string itself, even though I did init my TextField with my cell frames (see picture if needed).

2) I managed to change the UITextField text color but when the keyboard shows, it actually starts writing black again instead of white. Can I change this ?

Sorry for my bad english, not my native language but still trying and thank you for your help

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *identifier = @"id";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if (cell == nil){
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
   }
   if (indexPath.section == 0){
    self.LastName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
    self.LastName.placeholder= @"Name";
    self.LastName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.LastName.delegate = self;
    self.LastName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.LastName setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.LastName];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";

cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

First cell is my UITextField and second is my normal centered cell (i dont own 10 reputations so i can just give you guys a link to the image, sorry .. http://s22.postimg.org/sep2kcvrl/not_Working.png

Comment: do you want to center the text in the textfield or center the textfield itself?

Comment: I'd like to get the same result than cell.textLabel.textAlignment, center the string into the cell and not starting to write from the center till right corner. I dont know if it was clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just changing the color of placeholder text , to change the color of the text in the text field:

```
 [self.LastName setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

To align the placeholder and text field's text to center:

```
[self.LastName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: Simply setting the color worked well for the keyboard problem thank you but I still get the same result as on my picture even with your fix about the alignment, it keeps aligning the begining of the string instead of the string itself, sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Regarding second question:

There is "defaultTextAttributes" property in UITextField you can use for the color ( Available in iOS7+ ).

```
NSMutableDictionary* textFieldAttrib = [[self.textField defaultTextAttributes] mutableCopy];
textFieldAttrib[@"NSColor"] = [UIColor redColor];
self.textField.defaultTextAttributes = textFieldAttrib;
```

You can change the placeholder color also via the "attributedPlaceholder" property ( Available in iOS6+ ).

```
NSString *placeHolderText = @"some placeholder";
NSAttributedString *placeholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: placeHolderText
                                                                  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]}];

self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder;
```